# how match list and dictionary accordingly Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 1 list and 1 dictionary.
I would like to find the sentence which contains the words from mykeys list.

```
mykeys=['city', 'salon', 'last', 'website', 'car', 'offense', 'open', 'day', 'apple','tree']
mydict={u'00:01:00,880 --> 00:01:34,550': u'created by at the insistence of open and opened, 'u'the little boys, to cater last object to the fact that the mantle Arnold fall with an eye and water on the map and at the salon of the damage of a now will forgive if Mr. Odd enough for the rest of the fat of the day last of the best place to run they saw finances of a sense of hope that they say the.',
        u'00:01:34,710 --> 00:02:00,460': u'lot at the at the end of that call of the key to a loss of the holder of the offense of the offense of the season sat, a lot to the city to city that the staff at the fourth of that.',
        u'00:00:30,080 --> 00:01:00,710': u'of the game is at a Sonoma world of cities wants any site at gained a son, some crying again and again and they will be if not as a starter for that CNS that and I and far made for the man at the one that ended up by a wall in java battled head up, finished 10 a week of school full time at Seattle king eight you did.',
        u'00:00:01,310 --> 00:00:30,080': u'The list of the din of the dossier scene of the site is the issues of stocks and sacked for you to close at least a minute, that uses of the Cincinnati at all of the east of science of the insisted a lot of the senate committees that king case out kingpins in Natal and they all died in Lima and begin and died of.'}
```

the mydict contains{ speechtime: speech sentences}

mykeys contains [10 keywords]

I would like to find the seech sentences which contains the keywords from mykey list.

for example:
the speech sentences matched will be as followings:

as it contains: city ,salon, last, offense, open, day.

```
{u'00:01:00,880 --> 00:01:34,550': u'created by at the insistence of open and opened, 'u'the little boys, to cater last object to the fact that the mantle Arnold fall with an eye and water on the map and at the salon of the damage of a now will forgive if Mr. Odd enough for the rest of the fat of the day last of the best place to run they saw finances of a sense of hope that they say the.',
 u'00:01:34,710 --> 00:02:00,460': u'lot at the at the end of that call of the key to a loss of the holder of the offense of the offense of the season sat, a lot to the city to city that the staff at the fourth of that.',}
```

the others cannot find the keywords.

so how to generate the matched result such as the newdic

```
newdic={u'00:01:00,880 --> 00:01:34,550': u'created by at the insistence of open and opened, 'u'the little boys, to cater last object to the fact that the mantle Arnold fall with an eye and water on the map and at the salon of the damage of a now will forgive if Mr. Odd enough for the rest of the fat of the day last of the best place to run they saw finances of a sense of hope that they say the.',
 u'00:01:34,710 --> 00:02:00,460': u'lot at the at the end of that call of the key to a loss of the holder of the offense of the offense of the season sat, a lot to the city to city that the staff at the fourth of that.',}
```

Comment: _All_ keywords or _any_ keywords?

Comment: How does `created by at the insistence...` match all the words in `mykeys`?

Comment: any keywords...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with `iteritems` to iterate over the dictionary, and then another `for` loop to iterate over your keys, searching for each key in each sentence.

```
mykeys = [ ... ]
mydict = { ... }

newdic = {}
for time,sentence in mydict.iteritems():
    for word in mykeys:
        if word in sentence:
            newdic[time] = sentence
            break

print(newdic)
```

If you are using Python 3, use `items` rather than `iteritems`.

Comment: I use the  :   match = (timing, Sentvalue)  matchlist.append(match), It will return me the duplicated result. Is your method return the unique match result ?

Answer (score 0):

```
newdic = {key:value for key, value in mydict.items() \
              if any(map(lambda x: x in mykeys, value.split(' ')))}
```

If using Python2, use itertitems() instead of items(). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the piece you want is to convert the sentence into a set of words, and check if the set of words intersects (&) with the set of keywords:

```
>>> for k, v in mydict.items():
...  words = set(v.split())
...  if words & set(mykeys):
...   print(k)
... 
00:01:00,880 --> 00:01:34,550
00:01:34,710 --> 00:02:00,460
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, you can iterate through the dictionary values, and then for each value test each of the words in mykeys, like this:

```
for v in mydict.values():
    for k in mykeys:
        if k in v:
            (k, v)
```

or as a list comprehension:

```
[(k, v) for v in mydict.values() for k in mykeys if k in v]
```

To get the speechtimes as well, try:

```
[(k, key, v) for key, v in mydict.items() for k in mykeys if k in v]
```

If you're using python 2, I think you need to use itervalues or iteritems instead of values or items.